# Why requiring javascript asynchronous loading under my webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webpack

I'm really struggling with odd codes.

I want to include some query parameters by `$.ajaxPrefilter` in all `jQuery` ajax request.
I found below the code make it if it load correctly synchronous order.
But, following code in entry.js loaded jscode in unpredictable order.Sometimes prefilter.js were preloaded ,the other time, post_ajaxs.js were preloaded.(I inspected server post message,and sometimes lack of data and I checked timing loading using chrome devtools).

```
require(['prefilter'])

$(function(){
    if($("#page_id").length > 0) {
        require([
             "src/common/post_ajax.js"
        ]);
    }
});
```

Why is it caused? I'm confused because I first thought require keyword is synchronous loading.
I show partial fragment of webpack.config.js may be related.

```
entry: {
 /webroot/js/entry.js: __dirname+"/src/entry.js"
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "prefilter": __dirname + "/src/common/prefilter.js",
  }
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/webroot/js/",
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "[hash].[id].js?" + (+new Date()),
    publicPath: "/js/"
},
plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            d3: "d3"
        })
    ]
```

I want to enforce prefilter.js preloaded and load post_ajax after it. Please, give me help.Any information I'll appreciate.

**Edit:**
Here is prefilter.js.

```
 $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, {'data[extra]':$("#some_id").val() }));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be scope problem because outer required js is global scope and not nested by function curly braces. Webpack might separate dependencies because I test two case using require.ensure nesting $(function{}) and putting require(['prefilter']) into $(function{})'s scope, both works correctly though it is my prediction.
But,more correct answer welcome if you have.